# Problem with loading the flask configuration file parameters into database module

Tags: flask

I have application factory factory.py, which loads .flaskenv file and gets the name (FLASK_CONFIG) of the running environment from there, which there is imported from config.py.

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request, send_from_directory, current_app
from config import envmode
from dotenv import load_dotenv

def create_app():
    load_dotenv('.flaskenv')
    app = Flask(__name__.split('.')[0], instance_relative_config=True)
    env = os.environ.get('FLASK_CONFIG')
    app.config.from_object(envmode[env])
```

**.flaskenv**

```
...
FLASK_CONFIG = development
```

Config file by itself loads all variables from .env
**.env**

```
DATABASE_URL = postgresql+psycopg://flask:flaskpass@localhost/flask
DEV_DATABASE_URL = sqlite:///test.db
```

**config.py**

```
import os, secrets
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
class Config(object):
    
class ProductionConfig(Config):
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL')

class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('DEV_DATABASE_URL')
    
envmode = {
'development': DevelopmentConfig,
'production': ProductionConfig
}
```

Hense, if we have **FLASK_CONFIG = development** inside .flaskenv file, application factory loads DevelopmentConfig from config.py, which has **SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = DEV_DATABASE_URL**, that is defined inside .env.
I have database.py module that has to create engine based what environment is set in .flaskenv.

```
engine = create_engine(current_app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'])
```

But when I run project with this setup, it gives error:
RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.
This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
the current application. To solve this, set up an application context
with app.app_context(). See the documentation for more information.

Kindly, advice how can I fix this issue so database.py will dynamicaly get SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI into database.py module?